# A non well formed numeric value encountered in php when showing total value

Tags: php, html

Whenever I input big values like 99, I would have a php warning, saying a non well-formed numeric value encountered in php, on the following codes below:

```
<td><?php echo number_format($product['quantity'] * $product['pax'])+0; ?></td>
$totalpax = $totalpax + ($product['quantity'] * $product['pax']);
<td align="right"><?php echo number_format($totalpax)+0; ?></td>
```

So I have a preset amount of 30 pax, so if user input 99 quantity of this product, quantity * pax = totalpax, it will display non wel-formed numeric value..... However, the warning does not show if the total pax is less than certain digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) will return a number represented as a string, you are trying to add the value `0` to this string, which is not possible.

If you wanted to add a trailing `0`, you need `.` to concatenate:

```
echo number_format($totalpax) . '0';
```

Otherwise, remove this `0`.

---

The error probably appears when the result is over 1000, that's when thousand separators start appearing in the `string_format()` result and your resulted string is no longer a numeric string that can automatically be parsed by PHP.